# Hibernate: Load entities with Formula

Tags: hibernate, orm, formula

Is it possible to load an entity using a Formula?

For example:

```
@formula("(select * from myEntity ent where ent.isLatest = TRUE )")
publicmyEntity getmyEntity()
{
    return this.associatedPatientJournalEntries;
}
```

if so, how does the mapping have to look.

Also, what are alternatives to using formulas to load certain entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but the formula looks:

```
select ent from myEntity ent where ent.isLatest
```

Another alternatives are,

```
mounting the entity in your method.

post loading method
```