# Selecting an entity from another table using a Hibernate formula

Tags: hibernate

I'm attempting to retrieve an entity from another table using Hibernate's @Formula annotation. Given the following code:

```
@Entity
class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id = null;

    // ...

    @Formula("(SELECT r FROM Result r WHERE test_id = id AND resultDate = (SELECT MAX(resultDate) FROM Result WHERE test_id = id))")
    private Result lastestResult;

    // ...

    public Result getLatestResult() {
        return latestResult;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The Result class looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Result {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id = null;

    @ManyToOne
    private Test test;

    // ...
}
```

But upon attempting to load a Test entity, I'm getting the error 'Column "TEST0_.RESULTDATE" not found'. I've tried a few other things as well involving the @JoinFormula annotation, but without any success. I also came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098722/hibernate-load-entities-with-formula), which seems to indicate that what I'm doing should work, but it doesn't. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, I've found the solution to this particular problem. Annotations on the `latestResult` property are as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT r.id FROM Result r WHERE resultDate = (SELECT MAX(sqr.resultDate) FROM Result sqr WHERE sqr.test_id = id))", referencedColumnName="id")),
})
private Result latestResult;
```

Comment: I had same "problem". Thanks to share your own solution.