# Get the entity with the maximum id value with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, orm

I want to get max value of giftManagement.point_To , which is from another table .But it is not picking data from table.

```
@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_offer_gen", sequenceName = "seq_offer")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_offer_gen")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gift_management_id", nullable = false)
    private GiftManagement giftManagement;

    @Column(name = "sms_delivery_status", nullable = false)
    private String smsDeliveryStatus;

    @Column(name = "offer_received_status", nullable = false)
    private String offerReceivedStatus;






 Offer offer = (Offer) session.createQuery("FROM Offer where customer.id =:customerId and max(giftManagement.point_To)")
                    .setParameter("customerId", id)
                    .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Refer this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675809/selecting-an-entity-from-another-table-using-a-hibernate-formula" which is related to your question

Comment: @karthika i don't need annotation. i need query to find max value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Offer offer = (Offer) session.createQuery(
    "select o " +
    "from Offer o " +
    "where o.id = ( select max(g.point_To) from Offer o1 join o1.giftManagement g where o1.customer.id =:customerId ) ")
.setParameter("customerId", id)
.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: in this query it will find max id , right??
so how can i find   giftManagement.point_To

Comment: actually  giftManagement  is from another table(foreign key). in that case does that query work??

Comment: If the Offer class has `@ManyToOne` mapping named giftManagement, it will work. Otherwise it will not work, and you'll have to run a theta-style join.